# How to visualize a message of type sensor_msgs/PointCloud2[] in Rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, sensor-msgs, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys, I hope you all are doing well. I am facing a problem related to visualizing a topic in Rviz. So, I have a custom message of type `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2[]`. I have created an instance of this message type and pushing `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` data to it and eventually publishing the final message/array on a topic, let's suppose `/topic_name`. My question is:

**How to visualize it inside Rviz?**

I can see the data by running `rostopic echo /topic_name`, but unfortunately can't see the topic name under topic section of `PointCloud2` display in Rviz. I would really appreciate your help on this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346975/how-to-visualize-a-message-of-type-sensor_msgs/pointcloud2%5B%5D-in-rviz?/) by [Anubhav Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/44804/anubhav-singh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2020-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you're using a custom message, you can't use the built-in displays, as they don't work with your message, only with the standard message set.

I believe you have two options:

1. write a new RViz display plugin which can consume your custom message (possibly extending the current `PointCloud2` display)
2. use an intermediate node to "unpack" your list of `PointCloud2` into separate messages and then republish those

Option 2 would incur lots of overhead, but would allow the use of the built-in display plugin for `PointCloud2`.

Option 1 would require you to write your own RViz display plugin, which comes with its own form of overhead.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-18**:
What you encounter is actually why the recommendation is to try and use standard messages as much as possible.

If you created your custom message because the `PointCloud2`s in the list "belong together", then perhaps looking into [wiki/message_filters](https://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) (`ExactTime` or `ApproximateTime`) may help here.

**Comment by [Anubhav Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/44804/anubhav-singh/) on 2020-03-19**:
Thank you so much for your answer. And, it completely make sense. What I did is create an object of type `pcl.PointCloud_PointXYZRGB()` and make elements of my array of type `PointCloud2` as its points using `.from_list` method . Then convert the PCL data to ROS messages and eventually publish it on a topic of type `PointCloud2`.